# Protect IL from Reverse Engineering

Tags: asp.net, security, clr

How can i protect my IL from reverse engineering ? Any Obsfuscator tool is available ? will it offer maximum security ?

Comment: See also these dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584828/protecting-my-code-from-reverse-engineering, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106794/what-do-you-use-to-protect-your-net-code-from-reverse-engineering, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506282/protect-net-code-from-reverse-engineering, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488884/how-easy-is-it-to-reverse-engineer-net-obfuscated-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545767/hide-c-windows-application-source-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199909/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator.html)

is a .net obfuscator.

***Using an obfuscator doesn't mean that the code cannot be reverse engineered. But it makes reverse engineering a bit harder.***

So it is not 100%.

There are other obfuscators also like

[Spices.Net Obfuscator](http://www.9rays.net/products/Spices.Obfuscator/Features.aspx)

[smartassembly](http://www.smartassembly.com/)

[Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net)

***Free***

[Skater .NET Obfuscator](http://www.rustemsoft.com/freeware_obfuscator.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such thing as maximum security. Dotfuscator mentioned by phoenix does a good job, but in the end what obfuscators do is to make it harder to reverse-engineer, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use these obfuscation tools but .net il is designed in such a way that it is very easy to reverse engineer. You will not be achieving any real security this way. The biggest mistake made here is commonly embedding credentials or encryption keys in the source code which bad guys can then disassemble and read. Be very sure you are not doing this.

You can however test how well the obfuscator worked with the .net reflector which will disassemble .net code for you http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 0):

You should check [BitHelmet](http://www.bithelmet.com) obfuscator.

Great protection for less money.